# UWP Parse Windows.Storage.StorageFolder and add in a TreeView

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

I want to parse a StorageFolder that the user picks and create a TreeView which shows its tree structure. This is when I ask to him to choose a file :

```
private async void browserPathGitDirButton_ClickAsync(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
            folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            if(folder != null)
            {
                parser.CreateTreeView(tree, folder);
                tree.UpdateLayout();
            }    
 }
```

After he has picked, I call this method :

```
 public void CreateTreeView(TreeView tree)
    {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("root : " + root.Name);
                TreeViewItem racine = new TreeViewItem { Header = root.Name };
                racine.Tag = root.Path;
                tree.Items.Add(ParseStorageAsync(root));
    }
```

And this method too :

```
public async Task<TreeViewItem> ParseStorageAsync(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storage)
        {
            var dirNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = storage.Name };

            //directories
            foreach (var dir in await storage.GetFoldersAsync())
            {
                dirNode.Items.Add(ParseStorageAsync(dir));
            }

            //files
            foreach (var file in await storage.GetFilesAsync())
            {

                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name),
                    Tag = file.Path

                };
                dirNode.Items.Add(item);
            }
            return dirNode;
        }
```

If I use the DirectoryInfo class instead of StorageFolder, it works but only in a WPF project and I have to do an UWP project.
The problem is that it prints this : [image: display]

because of the asynchronous method...

Is it possible to parse in an other way a folder in an UWP project ?

**EDIT** : My TreeView class is a library wrote on the Microsoft GitHub so it works well and this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a `Task` to the collection without executing it, you need to await your method

```
tree.Items.Add(await ParseStorageAsync(root));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm starting with c# and your answer is very very helpful !